# Use constructor injection for spring ConfigurationProperties subclasses

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, immutability

I was looking at this https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot and was wondering if it was possible to use constructor injection for these in order to enforce some immutability properties.

For example would it be possible to do this:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("my-config")
public class MyConfig {

    private final List<String> values;

    public MyConfig(@Value("${values}") List<String> values) {
        this.values = ImmutableList.copyOf(values);
    }
}
```

And then in my yml config have

```
my-config.values:
  - foo
  - bar
```

But I get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'values' in string value "${values}"
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `@ConfigurationProperties` isn't really set up for this sort of thing (but it'd probably make a good Jira ticket). When you use `@Value`, you're using the standard placeholders, which means that you'd need to say `@Value("my-config.values")`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

is possible with spring boot since version 2.2.0 documentation is here: [Constructor binding](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.1.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-constructor-binding) adding the new annotation ***@ConstructorBinding***.

Answer (score 5):

The [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config) states :

> Property values can be injected directly into your beans by using the
>   @Value annotation, accessed through Spring’s Environment abstraction,
>   **or** be bound to structured objects through @ConfigurationProperties.
>   :

You actually try to mix their behavior.
`values` is not a property of the Spring environment but `my-config.values` is.
Even declared inside `MyConfig` such as `@Value("${values})"` it doesn't change anything as  `@ConfigurationProperties`  bounds the properties to a structured object. And of course it doesn't create new properties in the Spring environment, that is where `@Value()` looks for to resolve the value expression.
Whereas the exception to resolve `${values}`.

As `MyConfig` is a component `@Value` should be what you need :

```
@Component
public class MyConfig {

    private final List<String> values;

    public MyConfig(@Value("${my-config.values}") List<String> values) {
        this.values = ImmutableList.copyOf(values);
    }
}
```

You could also prevent the mutability by protecting the setter with a check but this will detect the issue only at runtime :

```
@ConfigurationProperties("my-config")
public class MyConfig {

    private final List<String> values;

    public List<String> getValue(){
         return values;
    }
    public void setValue(List<String> values){  
         if (this.values != null){
             throw new IllegalArgumentException("...");
         }                    
         this.values = ImmutableList.copyOf(values);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For `@ConfigurationProperties` spring uses properties (or setter) injection only. So this class should be mutable.

Also, it is not necessary to have a constructor in this case (and `@Value` annotation can be skipped as well), and class can be as simple as this:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("my-config")
public class MyConfig {

   private List<String> values;
   //getter+setter
}
```

Comment: you are right about the getter setter way but the OP wants to avoid this way.

Comment: Yeah. I also wanted to stick to immutable approach, and decided to use usual POJO just to keep things simple

Comment: @MaxFarsikov Autowired MyConfig config; config.getValues(); works great. But how does one call config.getValues() in constructor? I am getting: "Cannot refer to an instance field config while explicitly invoking a constructor"

Comment: @Angelina, sorry, I didn't get your problem. Could you please ask a new question and attach code example where you have this error?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `@Value("${values}")` and just use *getters / setters*
Or use *SpEL* - `@Value("#{'${my-second-config.values}'.split(',')}"`

Also, take look at Spring boot [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-vs-value)
Example below:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
}

@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("my-config")
public static class MyConfig {

    private List<String> values;

    public List<String> getValues() {
        return values;
    }

    public void setValues(List<String> values) {
        this.values = ImmutableList.copyOf(values);
    }
}

@Configuration
public static class MySecondConfig {

    private final List<String> values;

    @Autowired
    public MySecondConfig(@Value("#{'${my-second-config.values}'.split(',')}") 
                                 List<String> values) {
        this.values = ImmutableList.copyOf(values);
    }

    public List<String> getValues() {
        return values;
    }
}

@Service
public static class MyService {

    private final MyConfig myConfig;
    private final MySecondConfig mySecondConfig;

    @Autowired
    public MyService(MyConfig myConfig, MySecondConfig mySecondConfig) {
        this.myConfig = myConfig;
        this.mySecondConfig = mySecondConfig;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void startUp() {
        myConfig.getValues().forEach(System.out::println);
        mySecondConfig.getValues().forEach(System.out::println);
    }

}

}
```

**application.properties** :

```
my-config.values[0]=a
my-config.values[1]=b
my-second-config.values=c,d
```

console output:
    `a`
    `b`
    `c`
    `d`

Answer (score 0):

`@ConfigurationProperties` binds the values with the given prefix. `@ConfigurationProperties` and `@Value` are not related. So `@Value` will not be a relative path to the path you mentioned with `@ConfigurationProperties`.
Also `@ConfigurationProperties` use setters to inject the values. If you wish to make properties immutable you'll have to tweak your setters in some way.

```
public void setProperty(String property){
    if(this.property == null){
        this.property = property;
    }
}
```