# What is best way to read properties from application.properties?

Tags: spring

So, I have created configuration class with `@Component` and `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "properties")`, set default values for some of my application properties and changed some of them in `application.yaml/properties`

Now, I know I can access it using `@Value("properties.*")` but it can lead to having many variables which will be repetitive in another classes too

```
@Value("${properties.user-id-length}")
private int userIdLength;
```

I also can access my configuration class (as it is Spring Bean) through `@Autowire` it to variable in every single class I need make use of it. The cons for that is that more complex configuration class containing inner classes, which contain inner classes etc. will not look too great in code

```
@Autowired // Not recommended, but for simplicity
private MyConfigurationClass myConfigurationClass;

// some method
int userIdLength = myConfigurationClass.getUserIdLength();
String serverLocation = myConfigurationClass.getAmazon().getSes().getSenderEmailAddress()
```

Another way is to create additional helper class like `Constant` and set needed static fields with `@Value` but it can be time consuming and I'm not sure it is THAT different from first solution

```
public static int USER_ID_LENGTH;

@Value("${properties.user-id-length}")
private void setUserIdLength(int length){
    Constant.USER_ID_LENGTH = length;
}
```

So, which aproach is the best? Or are there another ways to do that?

Comment: I'd use `@Value`..

Answer (score 0):

Well, not much of the feedback but in the meantime I figured out that using both `@Value` and `@ConfigurationProperties` leads to some problems.

`MyProp.class`

```
@Getter 
@Setter
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "prop")
public class MyProp{
   private String default = "Default String"
}
```

`SomeClass.class`

```
@Component
public class SomeClass.class{
   @Value("${prop.default}")
   public String message;
}
```

Above example causes Exception `BeanCreationException`

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'someClass': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'prop.default' in value "${prop.default}"
```

Explanation to this can be found [here in @davidxxx's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51790372/12152413) and occurs unless we set all fields in `application.properties`. Because of that my first proposal cannot be done in the terms I thought it can be done and explanation was not easy to find, so I hope it will help someone one day.